# What happens if I cache the same RDD twice in Spark

Tags: java, caching, apache-spark, rdd

I'm building a generic function which receives a RDD and does some calculations on it. Since I run more than one calculation on the input RDD I would like to cache it. For example:

```
public JavaRDD<String> foo(JavaRDD<String> r) {
    r.cache();
    JavaRDD t1 = r... //Some calculations
    JavaRDD t2 = r... //Other calculations
    return t1.union(t2);
}
```

My question is, since `r` is given to me it may or may not already be cached. If it is cached and I call cache on it again, will spark create a new layer of cache meaning that while `t1` and `t2` are calculated I will have two instances of `r` in the cache? or will spark is aware of the fact that `r` is cached and will ignore it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Nothing**. If you call `cache` on a cached RDD, nothing happens, RDD will be cached (once). Caching, like many other transformations, is lazy:

- When you call `cache`, the RDD's `storageLevel` is set to `MEMORY_ONLY`
- When you call `cache` again, it's set to the same value (no change)
- Upon evaluation, when underlying RDD is materialized, Spark will check the RDD's `storageLevel` and if it requires caching, it will cache it.

So you're safe.

Comment: Regarding your note, it is something I was wondering for a while now and didn't found any record of this. If your answer is right and calling cache only change a flag in the RDD object, why can't I use the same object?

Comment: I will explain my question on the note a bit. If there was RDD called `orig` and someone out side the function did `r = orig.cache();` then I in the function call `cached = r.cache();`. If what you are saying is true I will end up with the same data stored twice in the cache, once as `r` and once as `cached`, wouldn't I?

Comment: You're right - I'm wrong. No need to use the `cache` returned value, it returns `this` - same exact RDD.

Comment: Let's say, I have -   ` rdd1= SC.wholetextfile(......); rdd1.cache(); rdd1= rdd1.map(.....); rdd1.cache(); rdd1.count();.  `        Will it cache only once or will it overwrite previous cache as some transformation has happened on same rdd?

Answer (score 2):

just test on my cluster, Zohar is right, nothing happens, it will just cache the RDD for once. The reason, I think, is that every RDD has an `id` internally, spark will use the `id` to mark whether a RDD have been cached or not. so cache one RDD for multiple times will do nothing.

bellow is my code and screenshot:

[image]
[image]

updated [ add code as required ]

---

```
### cache and count, then will show the storage info on WEB UI

raw_file = sc.wholeTextFiles('hdfs://10.21.208.21:8020/user/mercury/names', minPartitions=40)\
                 .setName("raw_file")\
                 .cache()
raw_file.count()

### try to cache and count again, then take a look at the WEB UI, nothing changes

raw_file.cache()
raw_file.count()

### try to change rdd's name and cache and count again, to see will it cache a new rdd as the new name again, still 
### nothing changes, so I think maybe it is using the RDD id as a mark, for more we need to take a detailed read on 
### the document even then source code

raw_file.setName("raw_file_2")
raw_file.cache().count()
```

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to know If what @TzachZohar saying regarding cache() is true. if so, wouldn't you needed to write `raw_file = raw_file.cache()`?

Comment: @RoeeGavirel cache is just a method of RDD, it returns nothing, here is the document : http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.cache