# Performance Impact of RDD to JavaRDD conversion

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a code something like this and I want to work on JavaRDD instead of RDD. So, I'm doing conversion here. I would like to know the performance impact of this transformation specially when I'm dealing with GBs of data.

```
RDD<String> textFile = sc.textFile(filePath, 2);
JavaRDD<String> javaRDD = textFile.toJavaRDD();
```

Is this wide transformation or narrow ?
What is the difference between JavaRDD and RDD ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no significant performance penalty - `JavaRDD` is a simple wrapper around `RDD` just to make calls from Java code more convenient. It holds the original `RDD` as its member, and calls that member's method on any method invocation, for example (from [JavaRDD.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.scala#L40)):

```
def cache(): JavaRDD[T] = wrapRDD(rdd.cache())
```

`wrapRDD` boils down to something like `new JavaRDD[T](rdd)`, so the only performance penalty is creating a thin Java object for every method invocation, but that's entirely negligible as it's not done per element in the RDD, but once for the entire object.

Comment: so tis is just an utility function which will not fall under either narrow or wide .  am I rit here ?

Comment: @BalajiReddy My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36196735/1870803) may shed some more light on the actual transformation.